# inconsequent csv import on strings and numerics

Tags: r, csv, numeric

I have a CSV File ("Alles.csv") containing the following data

```
DraftFore;DraftAft;HeadGyro;HeadMagnetic;WindDirection;WindSpeed;WaveDirection;RollHeight;Roll degree;Pitchdegree;Bearing;Distance;Current Speed
10.15;11.36;76.00;81.00;60.00;11.00;124.00;0.20;1.50;0.70;56.00;4.50;
10.17;11.39;83.00;87.00;80.00;16.00;112.00;1.10;1.60;0.60;45.00;3.90;
10.20;11.42;82.00;87.00;66.00;18.00;134.00;1.30;1.60;0.60;48.00;3.60;
10.24;11.43;60.00;65.00;30.00;18.00;143.00;1.40;1.70;0.80;20.00;4.50;
etc
```

When i import this by:

```
dat3 = read.csv(file="Alles3.csv", header = TRUE,sep=";",  stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings=c("NA", ""))
```

and print a value for DraftFore, you see:

```
dat3[1,2]
[1] "10.15"
```

When i do the same for HeadMagnetic

```
> dat3[1,4]
[1] 81
```

So, the [1,2] is a string, and [1,4] is a numeric value.

How is this possible please?

Comment: `dat3[1,2]` gives you the first row, second column. So DraftAft, not DraftFore.

Comment: Can you link to your `Alles.csv` file? Probably you have a spurious value in there. You could try and find it by `tail(sort(unique(dat3[, 1])))` which will extract the unique values, sort them (numerical first) and then only show the last 6, which may not be numbers.

Comment: You say you have a CSV file `Alles.csv` but you are reading `Alles3.csv`. I tried the excerpt you have given together with the read statement shown and the result is ok. You could also use `str(dat3)` to see what might be going on.

Comment: I always find `data.table`'s `fread` very useful for reading in data, which is both fast and very robust!

Comment: Also check the first field of your complete CSV to see if a field contains something that is not a number.

Comment: If using Excel to create or manage csv, be sure to check column formatting of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected by MikeRSpencer, i had spurious values in my CSV files.

finally found out how to easily check this by using:

```
head(dat3$DraftAft[is.na(as.numeric(dat3$DraftAft))])
```